# jquery stick element to bottom of browser viewport when the bottom edge of element reaches it - with resize.browsersize to update variables

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rwr4X/2/

I have made a jquery script - its not great and bulky, but it half works...

```
var $buzz = $('#buzz'),
    viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
    buzzHeight = 182,
    buzzTop = $buzz.offset().top + buzzHeight,
    buzzPosition = buzzTop - viewportHeight;

$(window).bind("resize.browsersize", function () {

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        buzzTop = $buzz.offset().top + buzzHeight,
        buzzPosition = buzzTop - viewportHeight;

}).trigger("resize.browsersize");

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= buzzPosition) {

        $buzz.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: 0
        });

    } else {

        $buzz.removeAttr("style");

    }

});
```

Now the script above works, but only to the initial viewportHeight variables.

Basically on my real project I have ajax elements, and font-face, and various size animations on my page. And when the browser viewport size changes, I cant seem to get the variables to update, and it causes buzz to jump.

Please see my fiddle with the above script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rwr4X/2/

If you scroll down the page, you will see buzz appear, and when the bottom edge of the img reaches the bottom on the viewport, the position switches to fixed. And appears to be seamless and flows nicely.

However if you simulate my page getting bigger by ajax, etc - click the blue and green divs in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwr4X/2/) to add 50px on each click. Then if you scroll up and down you will see that buzz jumps/skips when the scroll point is reached. This is because my scrollTo variables have not updated to the new size of the viewport.

Can anyone please help me fix it, so if the viewport changes size, buzz always seems to stick to the bottom of the viewport seamlessly.

Thanks in advance.

View fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwr4X/2/